# JQuery.TextnTags plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I am trying to implement a Facebook and Twitter like status posting textbox in which you can tag your friends or pages. After a 12 hour research on Google, I found this http://daniel-zahariev.github.io/jquery-textntags/. It's exactly what I wanted. But when I tried to implement it on JSFiddle, it didn't worked. Am I missing something? This is my fiddle code:

```js
$('textarea.tagged_text').textntags({
  onDataRequest: function(mode, query, triggerChar, callback) {
    var data = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'Daniel Zahariev',
      'img': 'http://example.com/img1.jpg',
      'type': 'contact'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Daniel Radcliffe',
      'img': 'http://example.com/img2.jpg',
      'type': 'contact'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Daniel Nathans',
      'img': 'http://example.com/img3.jpg',
      'type': 'contact'
    }];

    query = query.toLowerCase();
    var found = _.filter(data, function(item) {
      return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) > -1;
    });

    callback.call(this, found);
  }
});
```

```css
.textntags-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
}
.textntags-wrapper textarea {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: 18px;
  padding: 9px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: transparent;
  outline: 0;
  resize: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 17px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .textntags-wrapper textarea {
    padding: 9px 8px;
  }
}
.textntags-wrapper .textntags-tag-list {
  display: none;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10000;
  margin-top: -2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.148438);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.148438);
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.148438);
}
.textntags-wrapper .textntags-tag-list ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.textntags-wrapper .textntags-tag-list li {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
  width: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.textntags-wrapper .textntags-tag-list li:last-child {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.textntags-wrapper .textntags-tag-list li > img,
.textntags-wrapper .textntags-tag-list li > div.icon {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  -moz-background-origin: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.textntags-wrapper .textntags-tag-list li em {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: none;
}
.textntags-wrapper .textntags-tag-list li:hover,
.textntags-wrapper .textntags-tag-list li.active {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.textntags-wrapper .textntags-tag-list li b {
  background: #ffff99;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.textntags-wrapper .textntags-beautifier {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.textntags-wrapper .textntags-beautifier > div {
  color: #fff;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 17px;
  min-height: 17px;
}
.textntags-wrapper .textntags-beautifier > div > strong {
  font-weight: normal;
  background: #d8dfea;
  line-height: 16px;
}
.textntags-wrapper .textntags-beautifier > div > strong > span {
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://daniel-zahariev.github.io/jquery-textntags/jquery-textntags.js"></script>
<textarea class='tagged_text'></textarea>
```

Comment: The documentation says it [requires jQuery and underscore.js](http://daniel-zahariev.github.io/jquery-textntags/#dependencies), you do not seem to be including underscore.js

Comment: Thanks @PatrickEvans I missed that part of the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/6205ef8j/1/

There are two problems:

1. The extension depends on underscore.js so I added that without issue.
2. The extension depends on `$.browser` which has been deprecated. So I hardcoded `$.browser` to be true for `webkit` like so:

`$.browser = {webkit: true}`

You will need to use a shim to add back `$.browser` or use an old version of jQuery.

Comment: Thank you so much. I missed that part of the documentation. :)